# Python, How to use the @ in class method

Tags: python

I try to use the `@` in the class method. like this

```
class Dataset:
  @parse_func
  def get_next_batch(self):
      return self.generator.__next__()
```

and the parse function like this:

```
def parse_func(load_batch):
  def wrapper(**para):
    batch_files_path, batch_masks_path, batch_label = load_batch(**para)
    batch_images = []
    batch_masks = []
    for (file_path, mask_path) in zip(batch_files_path, batch_masks_path):
        image = cv2.imread(file_path)
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path)
        batch_images.append(image)
        batch_masks.append(mask)
    return np.asarray(batch_images, np.float32), np.asarray(batch_masks, np.uint8), batch_label

  return wrapper
```

However, when I call `dataset.get_next_batch()`, it will raise a `exception` as followed.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Do you know why raise this error and any solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to use wrapper(*args, **kwargs) and of course load_batch(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: But this decorator makes no sense when applied to that method

Comment: Yeah! It works, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wrapper(**kwargs)` accepts *named arguments only*. However, in instance methods, the `self` is *automatically* passed as the *first positional* argument. Since your method does not accept positional arguments, it fails.

You could edit to `wrapper(self, **kwargs)` or, more general `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`. However, the way you are using it, it is not clear what those arguments are.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change

```
def parse_func(load_batch):
  def wrapper(*para):
    batch_files_path, batch_masks_path, batch_label = load_batch(*para)
    batch_images = []
    batch_masks = []
    for (file_path, mask_path) in zip(batch_files_path, batch_masks_path):
        image = cv2.imread(file_path)
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path)
        batch_images.append(image)
        batch_masks.append(mask)
    return np.asarray(batch_images, np.float32), np.asarray(batch_masks, np.uint8), batch_label

  return wrapper()
```

`@` symbol mean a decorator function. Here, it means `parse_func(get_next_batch)`. So if the wrapper using the keyword params (`**para`), you just want to pass some params to the wrapper but you don't actually except for the `self` args. So here I replace the params to positional params `*para`.